# Getting an Object response from Javascript Post-Request

Tags: javascript, php, http

I have a problem with http-requests in javascript. When i use  `$http.get('http://...').then(function(response){})` I get an object response and I can select the value like the following:

```
response.data[Object.keys(response.data)][key].value.
```

But I heard that get-requests are unsecure, so I would like to use post-requests. When I use post-requests like this:

`$.post("http://example.php").done(function(data){})` , data is like a string, not an object. 
How can I get an object response like in the get-request before? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like below

```
$.post(url, dataToBeSent, function(data) {
  //data contains the JSON object
}, "json");
```